# Overlay line with stacked area chart in R-plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Is there a way to overlay a line with stacked area chart in Plotly R? Here is the sample code, but it is not getting me exactly what I want. I want the line not to be stacked on the area chart, but to be stand alone. It is similar to a supply demand problem.

```
library(plotly)

data <- t(USPersonalExpenditure)
data <- data.frame("year"=rownames(data), data)
data$test <- 200

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~year, y = ~Food.and.Tobacco, name = 'Food and Tobacco', 
                type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', stackgroup = 'one', fillcolor = '#F5FF8D')

fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~Household.Operation, name = 'Household Operation', 
                          fillcolor = '#50CB86')

fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~Medical.and.Health, name = 'Medical and Health', 
                          fillcolor = '#4C74C9')

fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~Personal.Care, name = 'Personal Care', 
                          fillcolor = '#700961')

fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~Private.Education, name = 'Private Education', 
                          fillcolor = '#312F44')

fig <- fig %>% layout(title = 'United States Personal Expenditures by Categories',
                      xaxis = list(title = "", showgrid = FALSE),
                      yaxis = list(title = "Expenditures (in billions of dollars)", 
                                   showgrid = FALSE))

fig %>% 
  add_lines(x= data$year, y = 200)
```

Comment: You need to define another stack group: `fig%>% 
  add_lines(x= data$year, y = 200, stackgroup = 'two', fill="none")`

Comment: Thank you @Marcelo. What if the second group is repetitive, for each of the stacked charts in group one, is there a way to not displaying the some of the groups? something like demand1, demand2, demand3, supply1,supply1, supply1. I dont want to stack supply1 three times on a row

Comment: If you want finer control of what should be stacked, I would manipulate the data to have the stacked values and not stack the lines on the chart.